# error when deploying my javaEE app - class not found jasypt/StrongPasswordEncryptor

Tags: java, server, wildfly, java-ee-6, jasypt

Hi i have a javaEE application with wildfly server i use the library jasypt to encrypt password and at the time to run my server app it throws me this jasypt.StrongPasswordEncryptor class not found exception and other exceptions, any ideas of what is this exception caused by? here's the
server output:

```
18:51:59,300 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."ProyectoServidor.ear"."ProyectoEJB-ejb.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."ProyectoServidor.ear"."ProyectoEJB-ejb.jar".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "ProyectoEJB-ejb.jar" of deployment "ProyectoServidor.ear"
        at org.jboss.as.server@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:189)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.fannog.proyectoservidor.utils.Encryptor with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.ProyectoServidor.ear.ProyectoEJB-ejb.jar" from Service Module Loader
        at org.jboss.as.server@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:78)
        at org.jboss.as.server@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndexUtil.findMethod(ClassReflectionIndexUtil.java:57)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.dd.DeploymentDescriptorMethodProcessor.handleStatelessSessionBean(DeploymentDescriptorMethodProcessor.java:99)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.dd.DeploymentDescriptorMethodProcessor.deploy(DeploymentDescriptorMethodProcessor.java:76)
        at org.jboss.as.server@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
        ... 8 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jasypt/util/password/StrongPasswordEncryptor
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:3297)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:2371)
        at org.jboss.as.server@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:72)
        at org.jboss.as.server@18.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
        ... 12 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jasypt.util.password.StrongPasswordEncryptor from [Module "deployment.ProyectoServidor.ear.ProyectoEJB-ejb.jar" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:200)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
        ... 17 more
```

Here is the wildfly server configuration (Standalone.xml) im using wildfly server wildfly-26.1.0.Final version

**LINK:** https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jBfLbo2Wm-3M8gR5Xw65zNyPBTQv-EynkvWb4gwVkQ4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This kind of error is often caused due server misconfiguration. Review your configuration and class loaders. Maybe, share your configuration to help find the issue.

Comment: Hi!, @HaroldoMacedo i edit my question and added my server standalone.xml configuration